# Set height of ListView onClick

Tags: android, listview, layoutparams

My ListView is currently stuck in a little small view-box on the bottom of my screen. When it's clicked, I want it to expand to some height. I've read guides on here on how to do that, but nothing seems to work. Here's my code here.

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.v("Miles", "Listview clicked");
            LayoutParams adapterParams = (LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
            adapterParams.height = 400;
            parent.setLayoutParams(adapterParams);
        }   
    });
```

And the layout that this code snippet is happening in:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="tribeTimes.EventFragment"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/event"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView
       android:background="@drawable/buttonborder_selector"
        android:id="@+id/likes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/event"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
       android:background="@drawable/buttonborder_selector"
       android:hint="@string/yourComment"
       android:id="@+id/yourComment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/likes"
       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:inputType="text" >
       <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@id/yourComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listInParent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `ListView` is "stuck in a little small view-box", and you have its height set to `wrap_content`, I'm not sure if you've only a couple of items in it, or if you've set the height some other way. As such, I've set the `ListView`'s initial height to `100dp` for the example. I'm sure you'll need to adjust some things.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tribeTimes.EventFragment"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView       
            android:id="@+id/likes"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder_selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/yourComment"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder_selector"
            android:hint="@string/yourComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="text" >
            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/listInParent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, when resizing the `ListView`, you'll need to add a layout rule to the parameters before setting them.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(list.getWidth(), 400);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
list.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `list.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 600))` worked to change the height of the listview itself. Now the problem is the other views aren't accordingly resized; as in, they don't collapse when the listview is made bigger.